# Is it safe to delete system files from linux subsystem for windows?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Good evening. Is it safe to delete linux subsystem for windows system files?

Suppose if I write `rm -Rf somesystemdir`, will anything to my main windows system?
Like will it delete system files of windows or damage it?

Comment: I would not remove Windows system files from WSL/WSL2 but directly from windows side.

Comment: I downloaded ubuntu terminal(from microsoft store) and I want to see what happens if I delete Linux system files. Nothing will happen to windows system?

Comment: If you delete Linux system files, your Ubuntu terminal will not work anymore. I would either uninstall Linux & Ubuntu Term from M$ store or from app control panel.